# Showing an array of messages in my blog app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am building an blogapp and allowed users to comment to the post with their name and if the user is not signed in it will show as anonamys. Its working but in my browser it is showing an array full of comments. How do i get rid of that. In my **Comments Controller**

```
def create
    params.permit!
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id if current_user || nil
    @comment.save
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

In the **form partial of comments**

```
<%= form_for [@post, @post.comments.build] do |f| %>
```

In my **Posts Controller Show Action**

```
<h4><%= @post.comments.count %> Comments</h4>
    <%= render partial: "comments/comment" %>
    <%= render partial: "comments/form" %>
```

And in my Comments Partial I have

```
<%= @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
<p class="comment_name"><strong><%= (comment.user.user_name if comment.user) || "Anonymous" %></strong></p>
<p class="comment_body"><%= comment.body %></p>
<p class="comment_time"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> Ago</p>
```

The array message in my browser is showing as

```
[#<Comment id: 13, name: nil, body: "nice pic", post_id: 17, created_at: "2015-09-27 20:54:22", updated_at: "2015-09-27 20:54:22", user_id: 8>, #<Comment id: 14, name: "sss", body: "sssss", post_id: 17, created_at: "2015-09-27 21:41:13", updated_at: "2015-09-27 21:41:13", user_id: nil>]
```

I have no clue where the mistake occurs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
<%= @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
```

which should be

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
```

Notice the change `<%= %>` to `<% %>`.

`<% %>` - execute the statement.
`<%= %>` - prints the output.